# Same ACF on two different pages

Tags: theme-development, advanced-custom-fields

I've made quite an extensive `page.php` using ACF-repeaters and the flexible content module (1000+ lines of code). The code is getting really spaghetti-like, and I'm not sure how to structure it so it's easier to read and maintain.

Here's a pseudo-code-version of it:

```
$all_fields = get_fields(); 
foreach( $all_fields as $field ):
  if( $field == 'field_1' ):
    // Deal with field_1
  elseif( $field == 'field_2' ):
    // Deal with field_2
  elseif( $field == 'field_3' ):
    // Deal with field_3
  ...
  ... etc.
  ... etc.
  endif;
endforeach;
```

Now I'm facing a challenge that will require me to structure the code better; I will need another page-template (`page-foobar.php`), that includes the same ACF-code as shown above.

On the one hand side, then I thought about making this whole thing into a (or several) functions and then sticking it in `functions.php`. But then I'm polluting the `functions.php`-file, which would suck.

Ideally, I would do this 'the WordPress way', if there is such a thing for what I'm doing, but I haven't heard of such a thing. So if there isn't one, - then I'd prefer to have a folder in my theme called 'acf-modules', and then a file for each field, containing a function like this:

```
function field_1( $field_information ){
  // Deal with $field_information
}
```

But should I then make an action in `functions.php`, requiring each file upon WordPress' `init`-hook? Is that really the cleanest/best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, structuring is partly a matter of taste, but it in this case it seems to be a good idea to include all the functions in a separate file. That includes the code that you would have in both template files. And rather than the chain of `elseif` you could use [PHP's switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). So you would have:

In your `functions.php` (just plain, not depending on a hook)

```
require_once (get_template_directory() . '/field-functions.php');
```

In your template files

```
deal_with_fields ();
```

In your `field-functions.php`

```
function deal_with_fields () {
  $all_fields = get_fields (); 
  foreach ($all_fields as $field) {
    switch ($field) {
      case 'field_1' : deal_with_field_1 ($field); break;
      case 'field_2' : deal_with_field_2 ($field); break;
      ....
      }
    }
  }

function deal_with_field_1 ($field) {
  do your thing;
  }

function deal_with_field_2 ($field) ....
```

Comment: I've just implemented that. And it works! However... In order to output HTML from inside one of those 'deal_with_field_X'-functions, then I need to echo it. So I would like to be able to write it like this: `<?php if( 1 < 3 ): ?><p>Yay!</p><?php endif; ?>` ... But I currently have to write it like this: `<?php if( 1 < 3 ): echo '<p>Yay!</p>'; endif; ?>`  ... ?

Comment: That´s how it goes. Template files are evaluated as html, interrupted by php-calls. Once you're in the PHP-domain, the only way to port things back to the html-domain is to echo it. You cannot have plain html in a functions file. WP wouldn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem again. Last time, I solve it using @cjbj's answer. This time I did something smarter, easier to deal with.

The downside of cjbj's answer is, that if you want a *rendered* file, then the functions `deal_with_field_1` and `deal_with_field_2` doesn't really work (unless you include something inside them or does a `echo file_get_contents(...)`.

What I did this time, was to have a switch-function in my `functions.php` and then keep all the sections in seperate files in a folder in the theme.

The switch-function looks like this:

```
function custom_acf_sections( $acf_sections ){
  foreach( $acf_sections as $section ){
    switch( $section['acf_fc_layout'] ){
      case "section_1":
        include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/acf-sections/section_1.php' );
        break;
      case "section_2":
        include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/acf-sections/section_2.php' );
        break;
      case "section_3":
        include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/acf-sections/section_3.php' );
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

It's almost the same as @cjbj's answer, - but I didn't figure it out until I had the same problem for the second time. So I figured I would share my solution.